# Microsoft list that filters the content based on 2 other lists using lookup columns. Hoping its easy

Tags: json, list, filtering, office365-apps

I am a new to Microsoft lists, so sorry if this is too easy for some, I want to filter data when adding a new item in a list based on a unique 'Pin' number that then filters the 'Task Details' based on the 'Pin' number chosen.
I have a 3 microsoft lists and want to keep list 1 & 2 separate;

1st called Team Pins

2nd called Team Tasks

3rd called Reports

The 1st list has a column named Pin with unique numbers that are looked up in the 2nd list called the same name. Several rows in the 2nd list will have the same unique Pin number with different data in a column called Task Title, amongst others.
I want to use the 3rd list to combine/filter the information available when I, or someone else, is adding another item row using these columns;
Master Pin - looks up the unique Pin number
Task Details - is filtered to look up only the Task Titles that reference the unique Pin number chosen from the Team Tasks list.

I used a json and tested but the filtering does not work;

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([Master_Pin] == lookup([Team_Pins], 'Pin', 'TaskDetail', [Master_Pin]), lookup([Teams_Tasks], 'Pin', [Master_Pin], 'TaskDetail'), '')",
  "style": {
    "display": "=if([Master_Pin] == lookup([Team_Pins], 'Pin', 'TaskDetail', [Master_Pin]), 'block', 'none')"
  }
}
```